# Gulp - How to pass attributes to 'lazypipe' function?

Tags: javascript, gulp

So I've just started using gulp in a project and thus far love it!  Immediately I noticed I wished to re-use certain tasks, but the process wasn't as straight-forward as I thought it would be. Long story, short - I found that ['lazypipe'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) was the common method for such.
Annoyingly though, I can't see how to pass attributes to the lazypipe Function.

MY ORIGINAL CODE:

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
  return scss([sourceScss], { sourcemap: true, style: 'compact' })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })]))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename('site.min.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../Styles'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetCss));
});
```

LAZY UPDATE: [...where I wish to pass the file name to processSCSS]

```
var processSCSS = lazypipe()
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(postcss,[autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] })])
    .pipe(minifyCSS)
    .pipe(rename, "** fileName **")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write, '.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../Styles' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, './Styles/');

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return scss(['./Styles/_themes/site.scss'], { sourcemap: true, style: 'compact' })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('Error!', err.message);
        })
        .pipe(processSCSS()); //pass fileName = 'site.min.css';
});

gulp.task('scssTheme', function () {
    return scss(['./Styles/_themes/bic.scss'], { sourcemap: true, style: 'compact' })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('Error!', err.message); 
        })
        .pipe(processSCSS()); //pass fileName = 'bic.min.css';
});
```

I believe it will be something trivial, but my skill-set is in its infancy at the moment re: gulp and javascript in general, unfortunately. Thanks for any thoughts / suggestions, very much appreciated, PP

Answer (score 0):

The function method, **bind**, allows you to create a function with arguments to be provided when the new function is called. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

To use it with lazypipe, you invoke bind on the gulp plugin and provide the arguments like so:

```
lazypipe()
  .pipe(processSCSS.bind(null, 'site.min.css'))
```

In this case, we don't need a "this" reference (first parameter of bind), so we pass null.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that lazypipe expects a function as argument, not the result of one, so you can't just write processSCSS**()** because that would execute it!

There are options to include extra arguments: bind obviously works (a normal JS feature, not related specifically to the plugin) - but based on how the plugin is written, either of these should work, too.

```
lazypipe()
  .pipe(processSCSS, 'site.min.css')
```

Or if you preferred (or had lots of arguments):

```
lazypipe()
  .pipe(function () {
    return processSCSS('site.min.css');
  });
```